# Need to prove that the A4 group is Normal sub-group of S4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I already proved that N, wich is a sub-group of S4 (4-permutations), which is all the permutations, which look's like: $(a,b)(c,d)$ (which are defintly are in A4 (even permutations of S4)) are a normal sub-group.

Now I want to show that S4 and N are the only non-trivial normal sub-groups, what lead me to prove that A4 is a normal sub-group.

So as I understand A4 is the union of N and more eight 3-permutations.

Now, my question is if those 3-permutations are a normal sub-group (and they are, because there are all the options of 3-permutations therefore from conjugacy we can conclude that it is normal) and N is a normal sub-group, is there union, which is A4, is also a normal sub-group?

Or did I a mistake in my previous conclusions ?

P.S - for a better understanding $$N=\left\{id,\left(12\right)\left(34\right),\left(13\right)\left(24\right),\left(14\right)\left(23\right)\right\}$$

And I need to show eather that they are the only normal sub-groups, how do I do that?

Comment: Hint: Index of $A_n$ in $S_n$ is 2,Hence Normal.

Comment: Hm, why is that in this case, can you to write more details? 
Index, as you mentioned, what do you mean? I know index as the amount of cosets.

Comment: Can you see that index of $An$ in $S_n$ is 2 ? Hint:Every permutation is either even or odd.

Comment: Oh, yes of course, you right. And how I show that those are the only normal sub-groups of S4 ?

Comment: Now you can use this easy exercise: Every subgroup of index 2 is Normal in $G$.Now as index of $A_n$ in $S_n$ is 2,hence you'r through.

Comment: Ok, so I'm left with the "onlyness" proof.

Comment: I'm little confused,are you trying to prove that only nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_4$ is $A_4$?

Comment: A4 and N, yes. As I described it at the top, sorry about the long descreption. 
$N = {id,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)}$.

For example, from first view I see another normal sub-group: 
$H={id,(124),(214),(234),(324),(134),(314),(123),(213)}$ isn't it? 
But if I don't get wrong there is a sentence, that tell's that if a sub-group of A(n) which includes all the 3-permutations is the whole A(n), something like that sounds femiliar?

Comment: The eight $3$-cycles are not a subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_n$ is the kernel of the signature morphism $\;\varepsilon\colon S_n\longrightarrow \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: I edited the question, there is another conduction, glad if you can help with it.

Answer (score 0):

A normal subgroup is a union of conjugacy classes, including the identity. The classes of $G=S_4$ are: $\{1\}$, $(1,2)(3,4)^G$ (length 3), $(1,2)^G$ (length 6), $(1,2,3)^G$ (length 8), and $(1,2,3,4)^G$ (length 6).

The only ways of adding up 1 and a submultiset of $\{3,6,6,8\}$ to get a divisor of $24$ are $1$, $1+3=4$, $1+3+8=12$, and $1+3+6+6+8=24$, and all of these combinations really do give normal subgroups of $S_4$, namely $1$, $N$, $A_4$, and $S_4$.